# Catch Blazor error "The following routes are ambiguous" at compile time?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

I have a dot net core Blazor app with two `*.razor` pages, 
one named `Index.razor` and the other `IndexDuplicate.razor`

Both have

```
@page "/Admin/Index"
```

So I get this error, but only during runtime.

```
InvalidOperationException: The following routes are ambiguous: 'Admin/Index' in 'BlazorApp1.Pages.Admin.IndexDuplicate' 'Admin/Index' in 'BlazorApp1.Pages.Admin.Index'
```

Of which I get why the error occurs.

Is there anyway to surface this error during compilation?

Comment: Sure, even at design time, just write your own [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)

Answer (score -1):

Please Change the `@page "/Admin/Index"` on a page like IndexDuplicate.razor => `@page "/Admin/IndexDuplicate"`